# get single element from list in C#

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list in which there are more than one items. Now I want to get first element's value of `tRecordCount`. I am trying, but getting an error **System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.**

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
 ((HiddenField)GridViewPagingControl.FindControl("TotalRows")).Value = Convert.ToString(List.First(item => item.tRecordCount == Convert.ToInt32("tRecordCount")));
```

I have tried `FirstOrDefault` and `Single` too, but none is working. The return type of tRecordCount is int.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Add some more code. Convert.ToInt32("AnyString") would always throw this error if the string is not a valid `integer`.

Comment: Your are doing to much in this line. At first get your record, than convert it and at the end you can set it to your control. This way it is easyer to find your error ;-)

Comment: Sure this part "Convert.ToInt32("tRecordCount")" will always throw the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be what you want is this.

```
((HiddenField)GridViewPagingControl.FindControl("TotalRows")).Value = Convert.ToString(List.First().tRecordCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have problem at statement

```
Convert.ToInt32("tRecordCount")
```

correct syntax in

```
Convert.ToInt32("/*valid integer value*/")
```

if tRecordCount is variable then this statement should be

```
Convert.ToInt32(tRecordCount)
```

Comment: but tRecordCount always returs int

Comment: then it should be Convert.ToInt32(tRecordCount),get rid of those '"'

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is:

```
Convert.ToInt32("tRecordCount")
```

You cannot convert string to int